# Geometric Realization of an Abstract Simplicial Complex

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

I am currently working through [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.01540v1.pdf) and something in the author's definition of geometric realisation of an abstract simplicial complex is unclear to me:

[image]

(some stuff in between that is not relevant to us)

[image]

Namely, the condition that $\vert \tau \vert = \vert \sigma \vert + 1$ seems wrong to me...? The map $\delta_i$ sends the standard $n$-simplex to the standard $n-1$ simplex:
\begin{equation*}
\delta_i : \Delta^n \rightarrow \Delta^{n-1}
\end{equation*}
hence i would expect $\tau$ to have a smaller cardinality than $\sigma$. What am I missing here?

Comment: It should be $\sigma_i(x)$ not $\delta_i(x)$ in the last line, otherwise too much got identified.

Comment: thank you! that eludes the dimension problem. can i ask what you mean by "too much got identified"?

Comment: Look at the case $\Delta_2$ with all its faces.  The geometric realisation you want is a closed triangle, but the given formula would have you identify e.g., $((\frac13+x,\frac13-x,\frac13), \{0,1,2\})$ with $((2/3,1/3),\{0,2\})$ all $x\in[-\frac13,\frac13]$, which isn't what you want for a triangle.

Comment: thank you! that makes perfect sense :)